# Solve the snake cube puzzle

Tags: recursion, kotlin

I wrote a solver for the [snake cube puzzle](https://www.google.de/search?q=snake+cube+puzzle). The solver can be easily adapted to arbitrary snakes.

Since the program takes only a few seconds to run, I didn't care to optimize for speed, instead I strived for clarity and simplicity.

Is it possible to avoid the repeated `Dir.` in the definition of `afterTurn`? If it weren't for this repetition, I would have spelled out the whole word `Direction`.

```kotlin
package de.roland_illig

/** The direction into which the snake's head may be pointing. */
enum class Dir(private val sym: String, val x: Int, val y: Int, val z: Int) {
    L("←", -1, 0, 0),
    R("→", 1, 0, 0),
    D("↓", 0, -1, 0),
    U("↑", 0, 1, 0),
    F("↙", 0, 0, -1),
    B("↗", 0, 0, 1);

    override fun toString() = sym
}

/** When the snake makes a turn, these are the possible new directions. */
private val afterTurn = mapOf(
    Dir.L to listOf(Dir.D, Dir.U, Dir.F, Dir.B),
    Dir.R to listOf(Dir.D, Dir.U, Dir.F, Dir.B),
    Dir.D to listOf(Dir.L, Dir.R, Dir.F, Dir.B),
    Dir.U to listOf(Dir.L, Dir.R, Dir.F, Dir.B),
    Dir.F to listOf(Dir.L, Dir.R, Dir.D, Dir.U),
    Dir.B to listOf(Dir.L, Dir.R, Dir.D, Dir.U),
)

data class Pos(val x: Int, val y: Int, val z: Int) {
    operator fun plus(dir: Dir) = Pos(x + dir.x, y + dir.y, z + dir.z)
    override fun toString() = "[$x $y $z]"
}

/** A rectangular cuboid space into which the snake is to be placed. */
class Space(private val xs: Int, private val ys: Int, private val zs: Int) {
    private val full = Array(xs) { Array(ys) { Array(zs) { false } } }
    private lateinit var start: Pos
    private val path = mutableListOf<Dir>()

    /**
     * List all possible ways in which the [snake] fits into the space.
     * Each "+" in the snake means a turn of direction,
     * each "-" means to keep the previous direction.
     * Each snake of n cubes is encoded as (n-2) characters.
     */
    fun solve(snake: String) {
        for (x in 0 until xs) {
            for (y in 0 until ys) {
                for (z in 0 until zs) {
                    start = Pos(x, y, z)
                    val dir = Dir.B
                    if (tryPut(dir, start)) {
                        solveRest(dir, start + dir, snake)
                        remove(start)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * First walk into [dir], then try to place a mini-cube at [pos].
     * If the rest of the [snake] starts with "+", turn,
     * otherwise continue in the same direction.
     */
    private fun solveRest(dir: Dir, pos: Pos, snake: String) {
        if (tryPut(dir, pos)) {
            if (snake.isEmpty()) {
                println("$start ${path.subList(1, path.size).joinToString(" ")}")
            } else if (snake[0] == '+') {
                for (nextDir in afterTurn[dir]!!) {
                    solveRest(nextDir, pos + nextDir, snake.substring(1))
                }
            } else {
                solveRest(dir, pos + dir, snake.substring(1))
            }
            remove(pos)
        }
    }

    private fun tryPut(dir: Dir, pos: Pos): Boolean {
        if (
            pos.x in 0 until xs &&
            pos.y in 0 until ys &&
            pos.z in 0 until zs &&
            !full[pos.x][pos.y][pos.z]
        ) {
            full[pos.x][pos.y][pos.z] = true
            path += dir
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun remove(pos: Pos) {
        assert(full[pos.x][pos.y][pos.z])
        full[pos.x][pos.y][pos.z] = false
        path.removeLast()
    }
}

fun main() {
    val space = Space(3, 3, 3)

    // https://www.philosshop.de/Schlangenwuerfel-Set-in-Holzbox-6-Stueck/6009
    space.solve("++++-+-+++++++++++-+-++++")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, you can avoid repetition by importing the names at the beginning of the file like so:

```
import Dir.L
import Dir.R
...
```

I would also suggest changing the one-letter names to something meaningful such as `Left`, `Right` etc..

---

Consider replacing `until` in `x in 0 until xs` with the new syntax: `x in 0..<xs`, it is similar to `..` and makes it clear that the higher bound is not included.

---

Avoid huge indentation blocks and high levels of indentation in general:

```
private fun solveRest(dir: Dir, pos: Pos, snake: String) {
    if (tryPut(dir, pos)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Indentation requires you to keep track of every condition that is responsible for creating it, making understanding your code harder. This problem can be solved with an early return:

```
private fun solveRest(dir: Dir, pos: Pos, snake: String) {
    if (!tryPut(dir, pos)) return

    ...
}
```

And just like that the indentation level of the entire method is reduced.

---

Nitpicks:

"dir" usually means "directory" so it's better to use the full word (as you pointed out in the question) to avoid confusion

Use leading commas in any vertical enumerations you write:

```
F("↙", 0, 0, -1),
B("↗", 0, 0, 1);
```

turns into

```
F("↙", 0, 0, -1),
B("↗", 0, 0, 1),
;
```

This way when you later decide to add another element of the enumeration, you only need to change 1 line instead of two:

```
F("↙", 0, 0, -1),
B("↗", 0, 0, 1);

turns into

F("↙", 0, 0, -1),
B("↗", 0, 0, 1), // line changed!
Q("?", 1, 1, 1); // line changed!
```

vs

```
F("↙", 0, 0, -1),
B("↗", 0, 0, 1),
;

turns into

F("↙", 0, 0, -1),
B("↗", 0, 0, 1),
Q("?", 1, 1, 1), // line changed!
;
```

It doesn't matter for a project like this, but it's a good practice when you start using VCS as you and your teammates can see when each line was last edited using Git Blame (or a similar mechanism). Adding a comma to an existing line messes up Blame since it creates a meaningless change. This extra change often covers something important, for example the commit when this entry was initially added to the enumeration.